# txt file to stream reader comma separated individual values

Tags: vb.net, txt

I am wanting to take a txt file that I have that is comma separated. For example:

```
706202212011417.G001,1024,20221201,172300,3600,35479,....
```

I am trying to figure out how to make an ArrayList and assign each individual comma separated value as an it's own item put it anywhere in the list.

For example, I want to assign the first comma-separated value to an `A1` variable, and then use this variable in a MessageBox: `"A1 is ******.***"`

I have been able to separate everything out, but I cannot seem to set the array to assign each item to its own variable.

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                      FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                        "C:\TestFolder\test.txt")
    MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                MsgBox(currentField)
            Next
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Pretty broad question, so only pretty broad advice.  You need a collection of some sort, perhaps a datatable or List(Of SomeCustomClass) then as you ready the file, just add the values to this collection, what works best will depend on exactly what you're doing with it after.  That said, there are plenty of 3rd party tools (check nugets) that make reading comma delimited data quite straight forward.

Comment: It's good that you formatted your code but you seem to have pasted it with no indenting, making it hard to read. Ideally, you should be copying and pasting directly from your code editor, so indenting will be maintained with no effort. If you're not doing that, please take the time to add the indenting yourself. If you'd like us to help you, do what you can to help us.

Comment: I would also point out that the fact that you have that loop with a `MsgBox` call inside it indicates that you aren't actually using the debugger properly, if at all. That loop is pointless and detrimental. For debugging purposes, you should be setting a breakpoint and using the Watch window or the like to view the entire contents of the array. If you don't know how to debug, you should stop what you're doing and learn.

Comment: I am fairly new to coding and not sure the words to use I have the plan and idea drawn out just trying to find a way for the computer to understand is difficult for me. I have updated my question and code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look more closely at the `currentRow` variable. This provides an index variable you can use to target individual values in the row: `currentRow(0)`, `currentRow(1)`, etc.